# Special characters to int, and then back

Tags: c++-cli, char, int

So what I want, is for example to convert the letter 'a' into 97 (such as it is in the ASCII table), and then convert 67 into 'a'.
I actually perform a load of mathematics and stuff to the letter, treating it as binary number - so the transition is necessary.
However for special characters it is not working nicely.

```
char c = 'ÿ';
int i = int(c);
wchar_t wTemp = static_cast<wchar_t>(i);
wchar_t* w = &wTemp;
String^ newI = gcnew String(w);
```

That symbol is just a random one I found in an image (the type of character that will need to be read). It just comes out as a completely different symbol. I have no idea why, or what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters above 0x7f (127) are probably converting to negative integer values.  Maybe change `c` to unsigned:

```
unsigned char c = 'ÿ';
int i = c;
```

Comment: Ahh this did it! I assumed that char would just have the same bounds as int, a poor assumption I suppose. Thanks! :D

Comment: Yup.  Converting between the encoding of the source code file and Unicode shouldn't be ignored either.  wchar_t c = L'ÿ' does give better odds.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't look quite right to me though I didn't run it. Here is a good example from MSDN how to convert from and to wchar_t:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631(v=vs.80).aspx

I don't believe there is anything special about 'special' characters.

Comment: That's what I used. However String() requires wchar_t* whereas static_cast gives out just wchar_t so I did how I know how to give an address?